# Trying to allow login with twitter by making api requests from my own server

Tags: node.js, express, twitter, passport.js, axios

I'm trying to use express and passport to login users via Twitter for an app. My server works and functions as expected when I hit the points directly. I get taken to a twitter login page and am redirected to a callback URL where I receive a user data object. My express server is running on port 8080 and my app is running on port 3000.

I also added in the following in an attempt to be able to use these server endpoints with my app that's running on a different port

```
var app = express()
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE')
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, 
  Content-Type, Accept')
  next()
})
```

However this isn't working when I actually use the end points within my app. I'm attempting to access the server like so within my app

```
this.loginWithTwitter = () => {
      axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/', {headers: {'Access-
          Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}})
      .then(res =>
          res.data
        )
      .then(user =>
          this.setState({user: user})
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested 
resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response 
had HTTP status code 400.
```

This is clearly not the fault of my express server (which is responding correctly with the user object). It's clearly not me forgetting to add Access Control for every origin. And its clearly not the twitter API blocking my express server. Could it be because my server and app are on different ports? Why wouldn't I be able to access the server if both are locally hosted and my server allows access? It seems to me that the greater issue here is how my component can possibly receive the data from a request to the server which needs to maintain that data and pass it down. Is there a better way?

Comment: Have you tried the option of `{ crossdomain: true }`?

Comment: Solved my own problem. I was trying to verify login on the server by linking directly to the passport oauth route. Which makes no sense. Instead I needed to put the oauth route as a link that a user has to click on. This takes them through the login process. THEN I can check the server to verify they've logged in somewhere in my component lifecycle.